# Export/Import Printer .DRS file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, zebra-printers

I have 30+ Windows 2012 r2 servers, each with 30+ Zebra printers installed.
I want to be able to use PowerShell import (and export) the human readable .DRS files that can be generated with the print management UI in both the Preferences and Default locations.

I have seen lots of mentions of this: `RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry` for import/export settings, but the file is not particularly readable, does not conform with requirements to store .DRS files, and I can't seem to get it to import the settings anyway.

I have admin on these servers, I am open to using the reg. but my understanding is that Zebras do custom things in the Devmode key - so it is not just a simple reg dump and conversion

I can use `Get-PrintConfiguration` and `Get-CimInstance` but not seeing Darkness, Speed, etc. in these outputs

```
$printerName = "Zebra_1" 
$compNameSource = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Printer = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='$PrinterName'"
$somePrinterConfig = Get-PrintConfiguration -ComputerName $compNameSource  -PrinterName $printerName
$Printer.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name, $_.Value
}
$somePrinterConfig.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name, $_.Value
}
```

output:

```
Name            : Caption
Value           : Zebra_1
CimType         : String
Flags           : Property, ReadOnly, NotModified
IsValueModified : False
Name            : Description
Value           : 
CimType         : String
Flags           : Property, ReadOnly, NotModified, NullValue
....
```

.DRS file:

```
[FileInfo]
Type=Driver Configuration File
Printer Type=201
[Barcodes]
BarcodeNum=6
[BARFONT0]
Name=EAN 13
UseHeight=1
JoinMode=2
StripTrailingSpaces=1
Kind=0
ID=1
Height=160
Expansion=1
Ratio=16908546
Flags=6164
…
[Parameters]
PaperSize=256
FormName=U
PageWidth=508
PageHeight=254
HDPI=300
VDPI=300
Orientation=3
Quantity=1
Cutter=0
BatchCut=0
Darkness=26
Speed=2
…
```